# Why Laravel REST controller $request->input is NULL?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I am following tutorial http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial and I have managed to write the similar method for my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    $employee->name = $request->input('name');
    //...
    $employee->save();

    return "Sucess updating user #" . $employee->id;
}
```

It is thought in tutorial that this code works but in reality var_dump($request->input) gives NULL. So - what $request variable should I use for getting the body of the request? I made var_dump($request) but the structure is unmanageably large. Actually I am suscpicous about this tutorial - **do we really need to list all the fields in the standard update procedure**?

Comment: If you find it complicated to read a var_dump from the object size; do this:          
`echo '<pre>' . print_r($request) . '</pre>';`

Comment: or in laravel: `dd($request);`

Comment: you can try `dd($request->all())` instead...

Answer (score 4):

You can access the input data with:

```
$input = $request->all();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input

However, I've also had to get the input in this manner when using AngularJS `$http` module:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: var_dump($request->all()) gives array(0) { }. This is strange because I am making test PUT request with body data from "I'm Only Resting" program. Where the body gets lost?

Answer (score 2):

for get all input

try it

```
$request = \Input::all();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch individual parameters from request object the you can do that with **input Method** of Request Class.

`$request->input("parameter_name");`

But if you want to fetch all request parameters then you can use `all` method which will return you an array of all the request key-value pairs

`$request->all()`

The thing you are missed is, you are calling `$request->input` which is null because `input` is **method** of Request class and not a property